# Repeated errors with Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I've been trying to set up FirebaseUI email and password authentication for the first time on a really basic website, but am experiencing multiple errors, and nothing shows up where the sign in/sign up UI should be. It's just empty, with only the loader showing. First, I have made sure that Firebase has properly been implemented, and hosting and deploys are working fine as well. I have also enabled email and password authentication in the console, and have followed the documentation to set things up. Here's what I've done so far:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.8.1/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.8.1/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Testing</h2>
     <h1>firebase auth practice</h1>
     <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
     <div id="loader">Loading...</div>

    <script>
        var firebaseConfig = {
            // I've omitted this part for the purposes of the question.
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        
        import * as firebase from 'firebase';
        import * as firebase from 'firebase/auth';

        var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

        ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
            signInOptions: [
                firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
            ]
            });

        var uiConfig = {
            callbacks: {
                signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
                return true;
                },
                uiShown: function() {
                document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
                }
            },
            signInFlow: 'popup',
            signInSuccessUrl: 'loggedin.html',
            signInOptions: [
                firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
            ],
            tosUrl: 'tos.html',
            privacyPolicyUrl: 'privacy.html'
            };

         ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
    </script>

</body>
```

`loggedin.html`, `tos.html`, and `privacy.html` are all pretty much empty. All of this has been taken from the documentation, but I got errors saying that firebase.auth() is not a function, and then I tried the `import` part, and got errors saying that the import statement cannot be used outside of a module. I have attempted to try what others with these errors did on SO, such as using `type="module"`, but to no avail. I suspect that the issue might have to do with the import bit, but cannot find any fixes yet, in either SO or the documentation.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not importing the Firebase Authentication SDK yet, which FirebaseUI depends on.

You'll want to add this line to your `script` section:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

Note that there may be many more problems, but this change should fix the `firebase.auth() is not a function` that you mentioned.

If you have more problems after this, please post a separate question for each, with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, as it's quite useful).